# iterating over each character of a String in ruby 1.8.6 (each_char)

Tags: ruby, string, iterator

I am new to ruby and currently trying to operate on each character separately from a base String in ruby. I am using ruby 1.8.6 and would like to do something like:

```
"ABCDEFG".each_char do |i|
  puts i
end
```

This produces a undefined method `each_char' error.

I was expecting to see a vertical output of:

```
A
B
C
D
..etc
```

Is the `each_char` method defined only for 1.9? I tried using the plain `each` method, but the block simply ouputs the entire string in one line. The only way I figure how to do this, which is rather inconvenient is to create an array of characters from the begining:

```
['A','B','C','D','...'].each do|i|
  puts i
end
```

This outputs the desired:

```
A
B
C
..etc
```

Is there perhaps a way to achive this output using an unmodified string to begin with?

I think the Java equivalent is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < aString.length(); i++){
  char currentChar = aString.charAt(i);
  System.out.println(currentChar);
}
```

Comment: "asfds".char.each....

Answer (score 122, accepted):

I have the same problem. I usually resort to `String#split`:

```
"ABCDEFG".split("").each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

I guess you could also implement it yourself like this:

```
class String
  def each_char
    self.split("").each { |i| yield i }
  end
end
```

**Edit:** yet another alternative is `String#each_byte`, available in Ruby 1.8.6, which returns the ASCII value of each char in an ASCII string:

```
"ABCDEFG".each_byte do |i|
  puts i.chr # Fixnum#chr converts any number to the ASCII char it represents
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip. It works fine. So what is the each_char method used for? Just for the newer version I suppose?

Comment: I haven't looked into it until now, but after Googling a bit, apparently it is mistakenly listed in the 1.8.6 docs but isn't available until 1.8.7.

Comment: The each_char method is for the *older* version, which doesn't otherwise have it.  Not yet documented at http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000862 and to my surprise, I see that each_char yields a string, like jeremy's split.

Answer (score 17):

Extending la_f0ka's comment, esp. if you also need the index position in your code, you should be able to do

```
s = 'ABCDEFG'
for pos in 0...s.length
    puts s[pos].chr
end
```

The `.chr` is important as Ruby < 1.9 [returns the code of the character at that position](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) instead of [a substring of one character at that position](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Comment: `0..s.length - 1` = `0...s.length`

Comment: Thanks @MatthewRock, changed.

Answer (score 9):

```
"ABCDEFG".chars.each do |char|
  puts char
end
```

also

```
"ABCDEFG".each_char {|char| p char}
```

Ruby version >2.5.1

Answer (score 1):

there is really a problem in 1.8.6.
and it's ok after this edition

in 1.8.6,you can add this:

```
requre 'jcode'
```

Answer (score 1):

But now you can do much more:

```
a = "cruel world"

a.scan(/\w+/)        #=> ["cruel", "world"]

a.scan(/.../)        #=> ["cru", "el ", "wor"]

a.scan(/(...)/)      #=> [["cru"], ["el "], ["wor"]]

a.scan(/(..)(..)/)   #=> [["cr", "ue"], ["l ", "wo"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Returns an array of characters in str. This is a shorthand for str.each_char.to_a. If a block is given, which is a deprecated form, works the same as each_char.

#### from [ruby-doc.org](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-chars)

**also now you can do string.chars**